# docker curl socket inside container

Tags: bash, docker, curl, libtorrent

I have a bash post process script for rtorrent.
In it I try to create a Container, start it and on the end remove it.
All via curl commands to the docker socket which i mounted into the container.
The command is successfully executed from rtorrent. The curl command for pushover is working nicely.

But I get a curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server Error Message for the docker curl commands.

Hope someone could point me in the right direction.

**Log:**

```
^@
---
^@/usr/local/bin/rtorrent-postprocess.sh /Pathtothedownload Nameofthedownload label
---
^@{"status":1,"request":"ec5c3c9c-5744-48f4-909b-68d38ec5e659"}curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server

--- Success ---
```

**Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
# rtorrent postprocess Script by Tobias
export LANG=de_DE.UTF-8

# The file for logging events from this script
LOGFILE="/config/rtorrent-postprocess.log"
#LOGFILE="./debug.log"

# Pfad des Downloads
FOLDER="$1"

# Name des Downloads
NAME="$2"

# Label des Downloads
LABEL="$3"

# Media Verzeichniss /data/Media
MEDIA="/data/Media"

# COMPLETE Verzeichniss mit label /data/torrent/completed/$3
COMPLETE="/data/torrent/completed/$3"

##############################################################################

function edate
{
  echo "`date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`    $1" >> "$LOGFILE"
}

function pushover {
  curl -s \
    -F "token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" \
    -F "user=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" \
    -F "message=$1 finished $2 $3 on `date +%d.%m.%y-%H:%m`" \
    https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json
}

edate " "
edate "Verzeichniss ist $COMPLETE"
edate "Name ist $NAME"
edate "Label ist $LABEL"
edate "rtorrent finished downloading $NAME"

pushover "rtorrent" "downloading" "$NAME"

edate "Starte Filebot - $COMPLETE/$NAME"

test_command() {
        curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -X POST "http://localhost/containers/${NAME}/wait" -H "accept: application/json"
}

curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "Image": "rednoah/filebot", "Cmd": ["-script", "fn:amc", "--output", "/Media", "--action", "move", "-non-strict", "/volume1", "--log-file", "/opt/rtorrentvpn/config/filebot.log", "--conflict", "auto", "--def", "artwork=n", "seriesFormat=Serien/{localize.eng.n}/Season {s.pad(2)}/{localize.eng.n} - {s00e00} - {localize.deu.t}", "movieFormat=Filme/{localize.deu.n} ({y})/{localize.deu.n} ({y})", "musicFormat=Musik/{artist}/{album}/{fn}"], "HostConfig": { "Binds": ["'$COMPLETE/$NAME':/volume1", "data:/data", "/data/Media:/Media"]} }' "http://localhost/containers/create?name=${NAME}"

curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -X POST "http://localhost/containers/${NAME}/start" -H "accept: application/json"

if [ "$(test_command)" == "200" ]; then
    edate "Status ist $test_command"
fi

curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -X DELETE "http://localhost/containers/${NAME}?force=true?v=true" -H "accept: application/json"

edate " "
edate "Filebot fertig"
```

Comment: The `docker.sock` is usually only writable by `root:docker`. Have you checked the file-permissions and group membership of the executing user?

Answer (score 1):

I changed the PUID and GUID to the root id. Thanks to [Robin479](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2878876/robin479)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50154153/docker-curl-socket-inside-container/50168374#comment87327521_50154153). Now everything is running as expected.